# Spring can't inject a bean from a different module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a root maven project with 2 modules inside it. Module A has the interfaces and main application class. Module B has module A as a dependency in pom.xml and implements interfaces. Why can't spring autowire the implementation from module B into module A?

Parent pom:

```xml
...
<packaging>pom</packaging>
...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
...
<modules>
  <module>A</module>
  <module>B</module>
</modules>
...
```

Module A pom, so the application runs from that particular module:

```xml
...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
...
```

Interface on module A:

```java
package com.company.exp;

public interface CommonInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Module B pom:

```xml
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.exp</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
...
```

Implementation in module B:

```java
package com.company.exp;

@Service
public class CommonInterfaceImpl implements CommonInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Doing something");
    }
}
```

Application class in module A:

```java
package com.company.exp;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.company.exp")
public class Application  {

    public final CommonInterface commonInterface;

    public Application(CommonInterface commonInterface) {
        this.commonInterface = commonInterface;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }
}
```

Application startup fails with the following message:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.company.exp.CommonInterface' in your configuration.
```

I've double checked the packages, the `scanBasePackages` value, the spring bean annotations (`@Service`). What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try moving the interface (temporarily) to project B? Just to check if that is actually the problem. If it is, can you load other classes (not beans) from that project? You might have a (runtime?) dependency issue.

Comment: If I move the interface from module A to module B, I cannot import it anymore in the module A, since there is no dependency on A to B. Injecting in general works - I have tried implementing the interface in module A and spring then of course sees it and is able to inject. The problem is module A can't see beans in module B even though they are part of the same parent project.

Comment: Module A is a sprin gboot application. You cannot use a spring boot jar as a dependency due to its structure. You either need to introduce a third module which contains the stuff you actually want to share, or apply [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.build.use-a-spring-boot-application-as-dependency). You also need to include module B into Module A (or at least in the module that has the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module B uses module A, so it can use `CommonInterface` at compile time; but module A does not use module B, so `CommonInterfaceImpl` is not available in the final application.

You have to move the interface in a shared module C, so that:

- B uses C
- A uses B (and, trasitively, C).

Comment: It seems that having a third one for interfaces is the only solution for this. I was expecting having A and B inside the same parent maven project would take care of the visibility, but it seems not. Thanks.

Comment: No, the list of modules in the root pom defines the modules that are affected by an `mvn` command executed on the root pom, it does not imply a dependency relation.